# CSV umlaut import in php doesn't show umlauts

Tags: php, csv, character-encoding, diacritics

this is my first question here. I'll try my best to explain it good.

I try to show a CSV as simple as i can on html output. Instead of "ö" it shows me nothing on UTF8 and on ISO it shows me "Âš"... I've tried it with utf8_encode and also with utf8_decode, which has showed the same result. When i've used mb_convert_encoding, it has showed me a question-mark.

The basic Code is the example from http://php.net/manual/de/function.fgetcsv.php.

Just to be safe: my header is on utf8. ;)

Comment: Example: On my CSV i have the Name "Köpke", on UTF8 it shows me "Kpke" , on ISO "KÂšpke".

Comment: OK, your page is in UTF-8. What about your input file?

Comment: I've exported it from Mac Excel to utf8.

Comment: So if your PHP script does simply `readfile('data.csv')` the output displays correctly? If not, then you definitely have some type of encoding mismatch.

Comment: however this can be, you're right. Excel for Mac displays CSV, even selected to be utf8, into Mac Roman. Thanks for your Help!